# Using Lapack when the entire matrix cannot be stored in a single array

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am trying to solve a linear system of equations, which forms a positive definite symmetric matrix, using LAPACK. I have a very large matrix size, so large that I cannot store all the elements in a single array. I recognized a pattern in my matrix values, so I would only store few values and can get the value of a particular element in the matrix by correlating it with the pattern I know. I would like to use LAPACK to solve this linear system of equations in fortran. But the functions I have seen, like sppsv(), only take the matrix in a particular format, which I cannot use as my computer memory is not sufficient for it to be written in that format. I am not sure how I should proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How big is your matrix? Roughly what percentage of elements are non-zero?

Comment: The matrix does not have any zero values. The matrix size is roughly 5,000,000×5,000,000. But only around 2,000,000 values are distinct in that matrix. So I store only these values.

Comment: OK, that is pretty chunky to say the least - if you do end up needing to store the whole matrix you're going to need ~3000 64Gbyte nodes. ScaLAPACK and and reasonable sized HPC facility may be the only way forward unless there is a nice structure in your matrix that allows some analytical progress (e.g. is it a circulant matrix). How many RHS? How accurate a solution? What do you want to do with the solution? To be honest at that size you might be better off asking in the computational science or maths group as a reformulation of solution method might be the way forward ...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Just to make my question more clear, I am trying to solve a semi-analytical numerical problem on a triangular grid. The element Cij of the matrix corresponds to ith node and jth node in the grid. According to the problem formulation, Cij depends only on the distance between these nodes, and therefore Cij=Cji . For instance, if we consider a triangular grid with nine nodes, the C matrix is a 9x9 matrix with Cii having a constant value, since the distance is zero. I have tried to number the grid in such a way that I get a Toeplitz matrix but have failed to do so.